# Unable to find source of environment variable

Tags: windows, command-line, vim, environment-variables

So I did the mistake of removing an earlier version of Vim manually on Windows without going through the "Uninstall Program" dialog. The result left me with the enviroment variables of "vim" and "gvim" pointing to the old, nonexistent folder when running the commands `vim` and `gvim` in cmd.exe.

I can not for the life of me figure out where these are being set. I checked the registry strings using regedit:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment**
and
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment**

However, none of these locations contain any keys pointing to the obsolete directory.
I also checked the PATH-variables using the normal Environment Variables dialog:

*Control Panel\System and Security\System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables*

but no cigar.

Does `cmd.exe` have its own environment variables defined somewhere, or where can I eventually look to find out where the pointers to the old Vim directory is being set?

Comment: Do a **full** registry search for old folder name (or part of it)

Comment: I actually solved it by reinstalling and uninstalling Vim again, although that doesn't really qualify as a solution. So the obsolete registry entries are probably gone now, but I'd still be interested in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Vim installer places wrapper `vim.bat` and `gvim.bat` scripts into the `C:\Windows` directory; I guess those were left-over from the old installation and attempted to launch Vim from the now-gone location. (Vim does this to avoid putting the Vim installation dir into the `PATH`; I'm not aware of the Vim installer defining any environment variables; so you didn't find any.)

Running the (new Vim) installer again (i.e. `%ProgramFiles%\vim\vim74\install.exe`) would have provided the option to re-create / overwrite those batch wrappers (this time with the correct path), but as I see, you've also fixed the problem.

Comment: When running the commands `vim` and `gvim` from cmd, the error message complained that it could not find the Vim executables in `C:\Program Files\vim\vim74\vim.exe` or something the likes. Point is it pointed to the Vim folder in the Program Files directory, not in the C:\Windows directory.